# plain_notification_token failed to Compile in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea, pubspec

I added this code to my flutter `pubspec.yaml` file

```
plain_notification_token:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/zionnite/plain_notification_token.git
```

but whenever I run the app on my android I encounter an error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/Users/apple/.pub-cache/git/plain_notification_token-3709a43167c63bd8f22570afe4fb21fe2e982c39/android/src/main/java/net/kikuchy/plain_notification_token/PlainNotificationTokenPlugin.java:77: error: local variable result is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                                        result.success(null);
                                        ^
/Users/apple/.pub-cache/git/plain_notification_token-3709a43167c63bd8f22570afe4fb21fe2e982c39/android/src/main/java/net/kikuchy/plain_notification_token/PlainNotificationTokenPlugin.java:81: error: local variable result is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                                    result.success(task.getResult().getToken());
                                    ^
Note: /Users/apple/.pub-cache/git/plain_notification_token-3709a43167c63bd8f22570afe4fb21fe2e982c39/android/src/main/java/net/kikuchy/plain_notification_token/PlainNotificationTokenPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':plain_notification_token:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 41s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

[image]

please how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The original package was updated recently, perhaps try the official one from pub.dev - https://pub.dev/packages/plain_notification_token, instead of the forked one from GitHub.

```yaml
plain_notification_token: 0.0.4
```